# socket.io routing issue with a node.js express 3 app running in a virtual directory with iisnode

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, iisnode

#### Errors:

Trying to access `http://localhost/appDirectory/socket.io` gives:
    `Cannot GET /appDirectory/socket.io`

Or to put it another way when trying to load the client file on the page I get this error:
    `GET http://localhost/appDirectory/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)`

If I load the client file as static content the connect line produces this error:
    `GET http://localhost/appDirectory/socket.io/1/?t=1365535131937 404 (Not Found)`

#### Server code:

```js
var express = require('express'),
namespace = require('express-namespace'),
routes = require('./routes'),
http = require('http'),
app = express(),
server = app.listen(process.env.PORT),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var appDir = '/appDirectory';

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('env', process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development');
  app.set('/views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(appDir, require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(appDir, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
});

app.get(appDir + '/', routes.index);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('message', 'lol');
});
```

#### Client code:

```js
<script src="/appDirectory/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect(appDir, { resource: appDir.substring(1) + '/socket.io' });
  socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected');
  });
</script>
```

The web config file that's getting this to work is...

#### Web.config:

```xml
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
  </handlers>
  <iisnode loggingEnabled="true" debuggingEnabled="true" debuggerPathSegment="debug" />
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="Debug" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="app.js/debug*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="None" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="app" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match url="*" negate="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My gut feeling is that the express routing is interfering with the socket.io routing or that the socket.io routing is not compatible with the virtual directory. I did see some mention of namespacing with socket.io and I did try the following...

```
io.of(appDir).on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('message', 'lol');
});
```

But that didn't seem to fix the problem.

I have tried a number of different things on the client code side but I don't think that is the root problem or the `http://localhost/appDirectory/socket.io/socket.io.js` would be working.

The application is running as a virtual directory and is built on:

```
- node.js 0.10.3 for windows
- iis 7
- iisnode 0.2.4
- express.js 3.0.0rc1  
- jade  
- socket.io
```

The module "**express namespace**" seems to make things work.

I am aware that iisnode was "*designed*" to be run as a separate site and I'm also aware that express doesn't like being in a virtual directory, but I am pretty sure this is possible.

### Interesting update!

Changing the line:

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

To:

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { resource: appDir + '/socket.io' });
```

Causes the iis worker process w3wp.exe to crash...
As seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2clc.png

However the url `http://localhost/appDirectory/socket.io` then seems to work.

### Failed attempts at fixing this FYI:

- adding the web.config setting for iisnode nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"

### Possible solution:

If you are stuggling with this same issue, I found this which might help you...
http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/01/hosting-socketio-websocket-apps-in-iis.html

Comment: Ever find a solution to IIS Crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track. Using the following configuration, it works for me (not using IIS, though):

```
// server
io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { resource : '/appDirectory/socket.io' });

// client
<script src="/appDirectory/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
...
var socket = io.connect('', { resource: 'appDirectory/socket.io' });
```

I wonder why your IIS process is crashing, could you post the image elsewhere (Dropbox, free image hoster) perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, very helpful to know that using that setup does work for you. I'm beginning to think that maybe iisnode has some kind of bug when dealing with websockets. here's the error message I am getting http://i.imgur.com/65RGia3.png?1

Comment: Not very useful, sadly, but I think you're right in that it might be iisnode. Can you run the app standalone with Node to make sure?

Comment: Running the app standalone appears to be working. So yeah def think it might be iisnode related... wondering if I should close off this question and see if I can find any answers that are iisnode / socket.io specific.

Comment: Yep just checked now and http://localhost/appDirectory/socket.io works with the resource option so it must definitely be iisnode

Comment: Well, at least you got that sorted out :) Hopefully you can get iisnode to work properly as well, good luck with that!

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of a stab in the dark, but if you're using Express 3.x, your problem may be that you're using the older Express 2.x syntax for hooking up Socket.io with Express.

See: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x#socketio-compatibility for the new integration method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm fairly confident that I am using the new syntax though.